# Batch file to convert multi-line text file to one long line text file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to write a simple windows batch file that reads from standard input a text file,
and writes to standard output the same content, but as one long line, sort of like what you would
get if you replaced each carriage-return-line-feed in the input by a blank.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: @steenhulthin - I thought that a for statement looping thru the lines in the input would be the way to go, but I had no idea how to get it to work.  The answer below is just what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could paste all lines together, if the total size is less than 8192 characters.
And echo the result to the new file with only one CR/LF at the end.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "text="
for/f "delims=" %%a in (multiLine.txt) do (
  set "text=!text!%%a"
)
>newFile.txt echo !text!
```

You could also use `set /p` to output text without CR/LF, but it can't handle equal signs nor white spaces at the front.

**EDIT:** The first solution works, but has problems with empty lines and lines with exclamation marks.

This is a solution that eliminates both problems.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set file=multiLine.txt

set "AllText="
for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%L in ('find /c /v "" %file%') do set /a "len=%%L"

<%file% ( 
    for /L %%n in (1,1,!len!) DO (
        set "line="
        set /p "line="
        set "AllText=!AllText!!line!"
    )
)
>newFile.txt echo(!AllText!
```

Comment: Thank you both.  This is just what I was looking for.  I'm a newbie at the command line.  For statements look very useful, but take some effort to learn.  Thanks.

Comment: @user198989- _Doesnt work on me_ says nothing! Is your computer on? Do you get an error message? What is the output?

Comment: I have the same issue, but all my lines togheter have more than 8192 characters. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

If your file is not big, you can slurp everything into memory. Example in vbscript

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFile="c:\test\file"
Set objFile=objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
strData = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
Wscript.Echo Replace(vbCrLf,"",strData)
```

Comment: I don't know anything about windows scripting yet, but thanks for the example.

Answer (score 0):

with powershell:

```
(gc c:\file) -join ''
```

Comment: I don't know anything at all about what your answer means, but I was intrigued by it, so I looked up a few things about powershell, which I had never heard of (I've used windows for years, but never used the command line, or scripting, or programming windows).  It looks extremely useful and powerful, and I now think I want to learn a little about powershell.  Thanks.